# Is there a way to disable apollo-link-dedup when using apollo useQuery?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

## Overview

I have a component that renders two child components. The child components uses apollo's `useQuery` to issue a request to the server. The issue is because `apollo-link-dedup` is included when using `apollo-client`, only one request is being sent to the server.

I've tried setting the context to `forceFetch: true` as specified [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/dedup/) but this doesn't seem to work with hooks.

Here's the query:

```
// Generated query from @graphql-codegen/cli
import { useGetUploadUrlsQuery } from 'types/graphql'

useGetUploadUrlsQuery({
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    context: {
     forceFetch: true,
    },
  })
```

**Note:** Passing in a unique variable bypasses the dedup. Any less hacky solution/workaround that anyone can come up with will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: If the requests are identical and happening simultaneously,  why would you want two separate requests fired?

Comment: Hey @DanielRearden, this is because each query returns a unique upload URL and in this scenario, I have two upload forms that both requires a unique upload URL.

Comment: Interesting use case. Seems like a documentation issue. See my answer below.

Comment: Hey @DanielRearden, adding `deduplication: false` doesn't seem to work. I've also tried `queryDeduplication: false` based on the docs you linked but this doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

This may be a documentation issue. I think the correct key to pass to `context` is `deduplication` with a value of `false`:

```
useGetUploadUrlsQuery({
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  context: {
   queryDeduplication: false,
  },
})
```

This is noted [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/ffa7047104bf89fbb0359335c535dfd602b3e77b/docs/source/networking/network-layer.md#query-deduplication). It's not really true that `apollo-link-dedup` is "included by default" as indicated in the README -- the logic might be, but the link itself is not.